# How to disable and re-enable touch event

Tags: android, touch-event

I have a ImageView custom with move and zoom guesture, and Button. How to disable touch event on ImageVIew when click Button first, and enable touch event on ImageVIew when click on Button second.
Thanks.

Comment: Enable and disable touch event of ImageView on each button's click listener.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it.But you can do it in the following way :

Make a public boolean variable

```
public boolean isClickedFirstTime = true;
```

make your imageView enabled true in xml and

onClick of your button

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button_id) { //whatever your id of button

    if(isClickedFirstTime)
                {
                imageView.setEnabled(false);
                isClickedFirstTime = false;
                }
                else
                {
                  imageView.setEnabled(true);
                  isClickedFirstTime = true;
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you make use of a boolean or an enum (ViewState below) that will help you manage the state of your activity. Once into your onTouchEvent callback, simply return if the activity doesn't have the desired state.

Here is a very brief example of how this could be done:

```
private enum ViewState {
    LOADING,    // Just an example of other states you could have
    VIEWING,
    EDITING;
}

private ViewState eViewState = ViewState.VIEWING;

/**
 * Event attached to your button.
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (eViewState == ViewState.EDITING)
        eViewState = ViewState.VIEWING;
    else
        eViewState = ViewState.EDITING;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Touch events should not be recorded if you're not editing anything.
    if (eViewState != ViewState.EDITING)
        return false;

    // ...
    // The rest of your code to scale, zoom, translate, etc
}
```